Pgfplot/tikz: node empty label error
What does the following MWE gives a Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
\documentclass[border=2pc,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
    declare function={
        f(\x) = (\x)^2;}]
\addplot[domain=0:4]{f(\x)};
\node[shape=circle,
  fill, minimum size=2pt] at (1,f(1)) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Enclose f(1) in curly braces. In general, when using parentheses in coordinates, you need to enclose the component in {}.
